# How do you leave the cursor at the *end* of the 'equalprg' output when using =?

Tags: vim

When using `=` to re-indent some text, what would be a good way of having the cursor end up at the end of the filtered output instead of at the beginning?

Comment: Have you tried using `']` to jump to the end afterward?

Comment: @NikitaKouevda, a lot of your comments should be answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`']`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#%27%5d) to jump to the end afterward. `=` is an [`operator`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#operator), and thus automatically sets the `[` and `]` marks, which denote the beginning and end of the region on which the operator was used.